# Twilio - Speech To Text with gather SpeechResult missing

Tags: java, twilio, speech-to-text, twilio-twiml

I have been getting started with Twilio Voice and the gather command in twiml. As described in the documentation of the java sdk I have provided the necessary configuration.

```
Gather gather = new Gather.Builder()
                .speechTimeout("auto")
                .language(Gather.Language.EN_US)
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .inputs(Gather.Input.SPEECH)
                .actionOnEmptyResult(true)
                .action(String.format("http://%s/call/speechtotext?sid=%s", headers.getHost().getHostName(), ""))
                .build();
```

The problem is that the body of the request to my action url does not have a SpeechResult property. I am always getting empty action and when I am setting .actionOnEmptyResult(False) not request is sent. The funny this is that the empty action is triggered every time I pause speaking.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: may because this is actionOnEmptyResult(true) true ? what if you place to false ?

Comment: then no action is triggered since SpeechResult is not present in the result